# Is there any way to ban the files with specific extention in specific dir in Linux

Tags: linux

What I want to do is to ban the files with specific file extention in specific dir, because many people upload files to the dir and I want these file names have beautiful formats.

The way I can imagine is to create such a csh/sh script file trigered by file creation, then delete the files with specific extention and alert an error.

How can I do this (how to autorun script when file being created) or any other elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an elegant way to do this - Linux treats extensions as just another part of the filename, so there's not special treatment on the OS' side.

The most elegant solution, considering there is an "upload" in the process, is to validate them at your server side, if it's a web application or anything similar.

The possible but not very elegant solution on the Linux side would be what you suggested, making a small utility using [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to watch file creation in the directory (maybe renaming too?), and delete the file if it doesn't fit the criteria.